# Error in normalizePath(path.expand(path), winslash, mustWork)

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio

I am trying to run the example code of Shiny, the app.R. If I click on "Run App", I have the following error :

> ```
> Error in normalizePath(path.expand(path), winslash, mustWork) : 
>   path[1]="XXXXXXX": Access is denied
> ```

According to my search it is a RStudio issue, but my other works fine.

Here is the R code :

```
require(shiny)
require(shinythemes)
require(DT)
require(DBI)
source("Shiny/global.R")


server <- function(input, output, session) {


  # Expression that generates a histogram. The expression is
  # wrapped in a call to renderPlot to indicate that:
  #
  #  1) It is "reactive" and therefore should re-execute automatically
  #     when inputs change
  #  2) Its output type is a plot

  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    x    <- faithful[, 2]  # Old Faithful Geyser data
    bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)

    # draw the histogram with the specified number of bins
    hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
  })
}

#==== UI  ====

ui <- shinyUI(
  fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("Hello Shiny!"),

    # Sidebar with a slider input for the number of bins
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        sliderInput("bins",
                    "Number of bins:",
                    min = 1,
                    max = 50,
                    value = 30)
      ),

      # Show a plot of the generated distribution
      mainPanel(
        plotOutput("distPlot")
      )
    )
  )

)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server, onStart = "global.R")
```

I did not  really change the example code, and the sessioninfo() is looking like this:

```
locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=German_Switzerland.1252  LC_CTYPE=German_Switzerland.1252    LC_MONETARY=German_Switzerland.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                        LC_TIME=German_Switzerland.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] DBI_0.7             DT_0.2              shinythemes_1.1.1   shiny_1.0.5         XML_3.98-1.9       
[6] stringr_1.2.0       plyr_1.8.4          data.table_1.10.4-2 RODBC_1.3-15       

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.13    digest_0.6.12   mime_0.5        R6_2.2.2        xtable_1.8-2    magrittr_1.5    stringi_1.1.5  
 [8] tools_3.3.2     htmlwidgets_0.9 rsconnect_0.8.5 httpuv_1.3.5    htmltools_0.3.6
>
```

Is there is a way to fix this ?

Comment: No shiny code runs?

Comment: Please update your post with `sessionInfo()`, and provide example app script that causes the error.

Comment: Can you try to get the `global.R` content also inside this code and try?

Comment: No this does not Help , I sitll have "Access is denied"

Comment: I know this question is old but just in case you are still having this issue: Are you on a german windows system (I guess it from your sessionInfo)? Is the path you xxx'ed in your question something like `C:\Programme\...` or `C:\Benutzer\...`? On current windows oses these are just links to the real folders (e.g. `C:\Program Files\...` and `C:\Users\...`) and `normalizePath()` cannot handle them properly (try to execute `normalizePath("C:\Programme")` vs. `normalizePath("C:\Program Files")`, the former will fail).